# Typeface.js rendering incorrectly (seems no antialising)

Tags: typeface.js

For some reason typeface.js isn't rendering my typeface correctly. I can't seem to dig anything up about it on google. Any ideas how to resolve this issue? It seems as if it renders the type without any anti-aliasing - in black and white only.

[alt text http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/7982/brokenk.jpg](http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/7982/brokenk.jpg)

Script is included in the page as follow:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="js/typeface-0.14.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="js/geosanslight_regular.typeface.js"></script>
```

If there's any other information I should add here, please let me know.

Comment: What browser? More info please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, needed to add class="typeface-js" to divs that uses the rendered typeface. Found it in the manual.